# Что лучше Spring или Hibernate?

Tags: spring, hibernate

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что лучше выбрать, *Spring* или *Hibernate*?

Comment: Смотря что Вам нужно. Обычно их используют вместе, потому что у них разные задачи и один дополняет другой.

Answer (score 3):

Это два разных инструмента для разных задач. 
Hibernate - мощный и в то же время громоздкий ORM фреймворк, позволяющий осуществлять работу с базой данных.
Spring - фреймворк, который включает в себя много разных фич, DI, AOP, MVC, Security и т.д. Для работы с базой существует Spring JDBC со своими JdbcTemplate.

Если вы именно в ключе работы с базой, Hibernate либо Spring JDBC, то тут что вам удобнее, зависит от задачи. Это вечный холивар на самом деле для всех проектов, что использовать для работы с базой.

Если вы просто в ключе фреймворков в целом, то они могут отлично дополнять друг друга в рамках целого проекта.

Answer (score 0):

Так это разные вещи. Spring это фреймворк или среда упрощенной разработки, которая включает в себя множество разных модулей. 
Hibernate это имплементация спецификации JPA. 
Вы можете использовать и одно и другое в одном проекте и эти вещи никак между собой не связаны.